# Append component dynamically into a map function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make it work exactly how it is working on this repo:
https://github.com/fellipefreiire/stackoverflowquestion

On the component Wrapper you can see that I coded manually every single Card and the respective content from each card when the Component opens.

It is working as intended but I'd like to know how I could shrink it using the map function.

It would be something like:

```
{cardsContent.map(content => (
          <Card
            key={content.id}
            title={content.title}
            text={content.text}
            icon={content.icon}
            active={content.id === active}
            onClick={() => handleActiveCard(content.id)}
          />
        ))}
```

But when I try it that way I can't make the components with each card specifics to render where they are. For example, the div which contains the first 3 cards should always appear below those 3 cards.

I'd like to know how can I make it happen without hardcoding everything!

Comment: have you tried pre-sorting your data before rendering it to ensure it's in the correct order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to chunk up your card content into the groups of threes, then map each chunk to a `Card` component ***and*** separately to a `Component` component.

Chunk utility:

```
const chunk = (arr, n = 1): any[] =>
  arr.length ? [arr.slice(0, n), ...chunk(arr.slice(n), n)] : [];
```

Mapping:

```
{chunk(cardsContent, 3).map((chunk: any, index) => (
  <Fragment key={index}>
    {chunk.map((content: any) => (
      <Card
        key={content.id}
        title={content.title}
        text={content.text}
        icon={content.icon}
        active={`${index},${content.id}` === active}
        onClick={() => handleActiveCard(`${index},${content.id}`)}
      />
    ))}
    {chunk.map(
      (content: any) =>
        active === `${index},${content.id}` && (
          <Component>Content of card {content.id}</Component>
        )
    )}
  </Fragment>
))}
```

[image: Edit append-component-dynamically-into-a-map-function]